# Django 2.1.5 SQL-Server how to save to Database with data from different table

Tags: sql-server, django, django-models

I'm trying to save data from a different table, but it won't work.
I have assigned the values to the fields and if I print out the fields they show me the right values, but won't save in my table.

my models:

```
class test(models.Model):
    id= models.IntegerField(db_column='id', primary_key=True)
    weight= models.IntegerField(db_column='weight', blank=True, null=True) 
    count= models.IntegerField(db_column='count', blank=True, null=True) 
   
class flow(models.Model):
    id= models.IntegerField(db_column='id', primary_key=True)
    weightkg= models.IntegerField(db_column='weightkg', blank=True, null=True) 
    counter= models.IntegerField(db_column='counter', blank=True, null=True)
```

I'm using Modelform

my view:

```
def flow_view(request):
    form = flowForm()

        if request.method == 'POST':

            form = flowForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():

                entnahme = test.objects.last()
                if entnahme.weight == 2000:
                    abschaltung = test.objects.get(pk=1)
                else:
                    abschaltung = test.objects.get(pk=2)

               
                weightkg=request.POST.get('weight')
                counter = abschaltung.count
                
                form.weightkg = weightkg
                form.counter= counter

                form.save()
                print(form.weightkg)
                print(form.counter)

     return render(request, "seiten/test.html")
```

I get the right data, and everything seems to work. Only the data won't save.

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the query object, change its parameters and then save:

```
test1 = test.objects.get(pk=1)
test1.weight = 100
test1.save() # test1 is now in your DB
```

Additionally you change can a table when saving other table,
In models:

```
class test(models.Model):
  //Your fields...

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs): #When you run test.save(), this will run
    if self.weight > 100:
      self.count = 2

    super().save(*args, **kwargs)  #Call the "real" save() method for test.

    flow1 = flow.objects.get(pk=1)
    flow1.counter = 3
    flow1.save()  # Saving flow table
```